# Android dynamic delivery without Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have an Android app with many games in it. I would like for each game to only be downloaded if the user wants to play that specific game, rather than having one giant APK file with all the games. Is it possible to utilize Android's dynamic delivery functionality without having the app on the Google Play Store? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that dynamic delivery operates by calling APIs in the Play Core Library, I don't think this is an option.

Comment: Yes, although there may be ways to inject replacements for these libraries or similar.